# Ways to see the result of $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

On my notes, it's written that a complex function is continuous iff writing $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+i\cdot v(x,y)$, where $u(x,y)$ is the real part of $f(z)$ and $v(x,y)$ the imaginary part, we have that $u$ and $v$ are continuous.

Suppose that I have the function $$f(z)=\exp(-1/z^4)\quad if\quad z\neq 0$$

and $0$ if $z=0$.

Imagine that we don't want to expand that $z^4=(x+yi)^4$ to separate this function. Is there a way to see that this function is not continuous on $z_0=0$ without having to separate it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Set $z=e^{i\pi/4}x$ and let $x\to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every complex function has a real part and an imaginary parte, under your definition every complex function is continuous. Perhaps that you forgot to add that $u$ and $v$ are continuous.

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then $\exp(-1/(x+xi)^4)=\exp(1/(4x^4))$, and therefore the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\exp(-1/(x+xi)^4)$$doesn't exist (in $\mathbb C$). In particular, the limit is not $f(0)$ and so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: edited Jose, thanks!

Comment: Adding to Jose’s answer; if you set $y$ or $x$ to zero then your function is real valued. That is $v$ is zero and you are examining $u$ at these points. Now you can use standard real function concepts to show $u$ is not continuous.

Comment: What I am suggesting changes the line we are restricting to from Jose’s

Comment: @Joel You are wrong. Doing that, the limit will be $0$, which is equal to $f(0)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos We could see also that if we set $z=re^{i\theta}$, and we make $r$ tend to $0$ and fix $\theta=\pi /4$ and $\theta=0$ (so the respective limits are $\infty$ and $0$), the limit doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @Relure Right. But making $r=0$ is useless, because then the limit is $0$, which is equal to $f(0)$. So, nothing can be deduced from this.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos of course you are right. I’ve been sleep deprived lately. Should have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted proof: suppose 
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\exp(-1/z^4)$$
exists. Then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and (I will use the same name)
$$f(z) = \exp(-1/z^4), z\ne0; \qquad f(0) = \lim_{z\to 0}\exp(-1/z^4)$$
is holomorphic in the whole plane. But $|z|\to\infty\implies f(z)\to 1$ and $f$ would be nonconstant and bounded.